# Ошибка при проверке input

Tags: php, javascript

Пробую сделать проверку на существование логина(емайла) в базе. При проверке пытаюсь сделать кнопку Disabled, если логина не существует. При попытке ввести логин на проверку запрос приходит с ответом, но состояние кнопок не меняется. А когда пытаюсь модифицировать div(который существует), ошибка. Хром пишет:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of
>   undefinedxmlhttp.onreadystatechange @.

Код:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  /* Функция, создающая экземпляр XMLHTTP */
  function getXmlHttp() {
    var xmlhttp;
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (E) {
        xmlhttp = false;
      }
    }
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
  }
  function checkLogin(username) {
    var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp(); // Создаём объект XMLHTTP
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'check_login.php', true); // Открываем асинхронное соединение
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); // Отправляем тип содержимого
    xmlhttp.send("username=" + encodeURIComponent(username)); // Отправляем POST-запрос
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { // Ждём ответа от сервера
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { // Ответ пришёл
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200) { // Сервер вернул код 200 (что хорошо)
          if (xmlhttp.responseText) .document.getElementById('login-submit').disabled = false;
          else document.getElementById("check_login").innerHTML = "Такого EMAIL не существует!"; .document.getElementById('login-submit') .disabled = true;

        }
      }
    };
  }
</script>
```

Comment: уберите первую точку в `.document.getElementById('login-submit').disabled` в обоих случаях, и не размещайте код в одну строчку с условиями в `if` и `else`

Comment: Забавно, парсер должен был сломаться ещё на точке перед `document`. Да, в хроме. У меня сломался, Вашу ошибку воспроизвести не удалось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите первую точку в `.document.getElementById('login-submit').disabled` в обоих случаях, и не размещайте код в одну строчку с условиями в `if` и `else`:

```
if (xmlhttp.responseText) {
  document.getElementById('login-submit').disabled = false;
} else {
  document.getElementById("check_login").innerHTML = "Такого EMAIL не существует!";
  document.getElementById('login-submit').disabled = true;
}
```